# I have a different opinion about my usage of the Python assert statement and I would like you to tell me why I am wrong

Tags: python, testing, assert

Please hear me out. I know how `assert` works.

For context, some of the applications and usages I have in mind involve mathematical optimization through a GUI, so the functions can be called hundreds of millions of times.

The `assert` statement is disabled in optimized mode (`-O`) so it is considered bad practice (read: *capital sin*) to rely on it as per most people's opinion (maybe it's more than an opinion, I don't know).

Say I have the following function that computes the area of a circle:

```
def area_circle(r):
    return 3.141592654 * (r**2)
```

Yes, I know, there are no docstrings. It's a toy  example. To make sure that `radius` is either an `int` or a `float`, I would do this:

```
def area_circle(r):
    assert isinstance(r, (int, float), 'TypeError: Expected int or float, not ' + type(r).__name__
    return 3.141592654 * (r**2)
```

My take on it should probably have me publicly executed, because I see it as a neat feature that allows me to do some input checking and such while I'm developing, but then when I reach a production-ready state, I can just disable those unecessary parts of the code in optimized mode. If my systems tests cover the workflows that lead to the usage of `area_circle`, then I personally dont wan't to see `raise` statements because they're just waste.

So how can I do an integrated systems tests in a way that doesn't slow down the application without using `assert`?

**EDIT 1**

Here are two additional pieces of information to consider:

1. There are no external sources of data, everything comes from the
   GUI;
2. Input validation is done directly in the GUI

Comment: Is what you are asking: "Is it ok to use `assert` instead of `raise XxxxException`?"

Comment: This sounds exactly how assert is meant to be used, what do you think other people's opinion is? In any case I don't think this question is suitable here and it will probably get closed.

Comment: I'm also pretty confused what you're asking. You acknowledge that `assert` is for debugging during development only and that's it's good for that. … Then what's your "different opinion" and what's your question?

Comment: @James Yes. I understand that this is what happens in the background or very close to it, but why would I use `raise` to validate function input for example when to me this is the job of a proper unit test?

Comment: @deceze My different opinion is that adding a `if condition: raise (...)` would bloat the code unecessarily, yet I have seen it in many places.

Comment: You're saying you want to avoid runtime checks and you're happy compensating that with unit tests and `assert` statements, and you're questioning the legitimacy of *any* runtime `raise` statement…?! Well… what if you're using any external data at all, and you want invalid data to cause exceptions? You cannot use unit tests for *every possible thing*, at some point you *will* need runtime checks and actual `raise` statements…

Comment: @deceze I should've made it clear that there is no external data. Everything is entered through the user interface and some checks are made at the GUI level to prevent say a user from entering a string instead of an integer or a float. My main concern is that the back-end can be used in batch mode and that I don't want any sort of testing to happen when that is so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thesis appears to be that `assert` statements are great for debugging (which they are), and that *you* in *your use case* can sufficiently unit test every code path that you can confidently switch them off during production to gain performance, and that you're now doubting ***every*** possible use of explicit `raise` statements.

Well, not every code can be tested to that degree. There is code "at the frontlines" which must do input validation **at runtime**, and that must use explicit checks and explicit `raise` statements. It's great that *you* have a case where your backend code doesn't need to worry about input validation because you're confident enough that this is handled at a previous layer. In such cases, by all means, don't do input validation and switch off your `assert` statements. That doesn't mean that's possible in every case. That frontend of yours for example will still need explicit runtime checks and may probably explicitly `raise` errors internally.

`raise` statements are for when your program encounters an *exceptional situation* that it cannot deal with. Your code makes an HTTP request to a remote server which responds with `500 Internal Error`. That's an *exceptional situation*. That's not the happy path for your code. That's a situation your code cannot deal with, and it can only occur at runtime, there's no way to prevent this through unit testing. In this case `raise`ing an exception is a very sensible thing to do.

Comment: Fair point, I changed the title to reflect that I'm not questioning the practice of raising exceptions as a whole. Thank you.